# Is there a way to "print" the name / position in media_list / media_list_player instance of th vlc.py

Tags: python, libvlc

I am trying to use VLC player, controlled by Python (`vlc.py` bindings), as a media player on my Pi. I create a MediaList and it starts to play, so far so good.

I need to get the current item postion to save it in a db, so I can go back to the last played track when I restart the MediaList after a reboot or similar.

It's running on my Raspberry 3b+ with newest Raspbian and Python 3.5.

```
import vlc

mrl1 = '....1.3gp'
mrl2 = '....2.3gp'

Instance = vlc.Instance('--input-repeat=-1', '--fullscreen', '--mouse-hide-timeout=0')

MediaList = Instance.media_list_new()

MediaList.add_media(Instance.media_new(mrl2))
MediaList.add_media(Instance.media_new(mrl1))

list_player = Instance.media_list_player_new()
list_player.set_media_list(MediaList)

list_player.next()
```

This is a raw piece of code of what I am trying, but it plays my songs one by one. I want to be able to print the current playing filename or the position in the media list to save it.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use events to be notified when the currently playing media changes.  You might have to experiment with a couple options to see which is the most reliable when using a media list

One option is the `MediaListPlayerNextItemSet` event

```py
def listPlayerCallback(event):
    print "listPlayerCallback:", event.type, event.u

list_player_events = list_player.event_manager()
list_player_events.event_attach(EventType.MediaListPlayerNextItemSet, listPlayerCallback)
```

The event passed in response to `MediaListPlayerNextItemSet` contains a `Media` item

```
event.u.media
```

Depending on your media, you might be able to pull meta data from it using the `get_meta` method

```
event.u.media.get_meta(0)
```

(There is an enumeration of meta data; 0 is the Title)

Alternatively, you might have better luck with the `MediaPlayerMediaChanged` event

```
media_player_events = mp.event_manager()
media_player_events.event_attach(EventType.MediaPlayerMediaChanged, listPlayerCallback)
```

The event data for that event is the same as above.

If pulling the meta data doesn't work, you might be able to do a straight comparison against the items in your list and then use that to index into a saved list of media filenames.

Comment: `event.u.media` doesn't seem to work. From https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/ it looks like `u` is a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer gives a hint on how to do it, but does not actually work. Since the edit queue is full, I will post a new answer.

The actual event is 'MediaListPlayerNextItemSet'.

```
media_player_events = media_list_player.event_manager()
media_player_events.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaListPlayerNextItemSet, lambda _: print("x"))
```